# MySQLでAUTO_INCREMENT属性を指定した場合に、PRIMARY KEY制約を付ける場合と付けない場合の違いは？

Tags: mysql

#### 知りたいこと

MySQLでAUTO_INCREMENT属性を指定したidカラムに、PRIMARY KEY制約を付ける場合と付けない場合では何が異なるか知りたい。

#### 疑問に思ったきっかけ

[MySQL リファレンスマニュアル](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/ja/example-auto-increment.html) には

> AUTO_INCREMENT 属性を使用すると、新しい行に一意の識別子を生成できます。

と掲載されていますが、すぐ下に書かれているSQL文には、PRIMARY KEYも書かれています。

```
CREATE TABLE animals (
     id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     name CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

この意味は、下記いずれですか？

- AUTO_INCREMENT 属性を使用するだけで、新しい行に一意の識別子を生成できる
- AUTO_INCREMENT 属性を指定した値にPRIMARY KEYを指定することで、新しい行に一意の識別子を生成できる

環境
MySQL5.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> この意味は、下記いずれですか？
> ・AUTO_INCREMENT 属性を使用するだけで、新しい行に一意の識別子を生成できる
> ・AUTO_INCREMENT 属性を指定した値にPRIMARY KEYを指定することで、新しい行に一意の識別子を生成できる

後者です。
カラム自体が重複を許す場合(単純なインデックスとしてのKEYを指定した場合など)、明示的にidを割り当てることで重複させることができます。
idを省略した場合などには重複しない一意の値(最大値+1)を生成します。

**Schema (MySQL v8.0)**

```
CREATE TABLE animals (
     id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     name CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
     KEY (id) -- 何らかのKEYがないとER_WRONG_AUTO_KEYが発生する
);

INSERT INTO animals (name) VALUES
    ('dog'),('cat'),('penguin');

INSERT INTO animals (id, name) VALUES
    (1, 'penguin'), -- 重複可
    (NULL, 'lax');  -- NOT NULLなので自動付番
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT * FROM animals;
```

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | dog |
| 2 | cat |
| 3 | penguin |
| 1 | penguin |
| 4 | lax |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cqQ3xTQD5QA9JpdRsmVpgr/0)